# vCenter - Active Directory integration - permissions on specific hosts

Tags: active-directory, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I have 4 ESXi hosts with 1 vCenter.

I manage the whole 4 hosts with the vCenter interface. How can I block access to specific hosts within vCenter based on the Active Directory user logged on the vCenter interface?

For instance I would like to create an AD group called "SuperUser vSphere" and another "User vSphere", and only the "SuperUser vSphere" group members should be allowed to view and manage all the hosts within vCenter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assign permissions on vCenter objects *at the level where the object is defined*.

For instance, to assign an admin group all rights on the cluster, you would add them as "administrator" on the Cluster level.

You can then assign permissions on groups of objecs, or even or individual VMs, to users and user groups - either vCenter or AD.

These permissions are very detailed - you can control who can start/stop etc. a VM, or change specific settings, or log onto the console, or change a vmdk, add a disk, etc. etc.

Fortunately, you can group permissions into Roles, which you can then assign.